# Converting float numpy arrays to string arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, converters

How would I be able to turn all float numpy arrays into strings arrays?

```
import numpy as np 

floats = np.array([1,3.4,0.678,11.1])
```

Expected output:

```
np.array(['1','3.4','0.678','11.1'])
```

Comment: `floats = floats.astype(str)`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way:

```
np.array([1,3.4,0.678,11.1]).astype(str)
```

output:

```
array(['1.0', '3.4', '0.678', '11.1'], dtype='<U32')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings = [str(value) for value in floats]
```

Comment: better to use `floats = floats.astype(str)`. Otherwise list comprehension  will have `strings` variable of type `list`